# Need data from couple of table in mysql using join or subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I have written below query in MYSQL :

```
SELECT ab.id, ab.name, creditAmt, debitAmt, creditAmt-debitAmt balance FROM ab
            JOIN (select sum(credit_amt) creditAmt from pq) i
            JOIN (select sum(debit_amt) debitAmt from pq) e
            WHERE ab.type = 'user' GROUP BY ab.user_eid
```

Below is My Table Structure for ab :

[image]

Below is My Table Structure for pq :

[image]

I want to show total balance available for both the ab.ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of subqueries, the more intuitive approach would be to join and group by the account. Note that you'd need to treat credit as positive number and debit as negative:

```
SELECT   ab.name, SUM(pq.credit - pq.debit) AS balance
FROM     ab
JOIN     pq ON ab.id = pq.ab_id
GROUP BY ab.name
```